# Localized strings without storyboard doesn't work

Tags: ios, nslocalizedstring

I am trying fix localized strings without using storyboards, but I have no idea how.

I created `localized.strings` and call

```
NSLocalizedString(@"Login", /* Login */)
```

With storyboard it works, but without storyboards it doesn't.

Comment: Did you call `genstrings` from the command line?

Comment: Nono, i will try it. Thank you